# Moving Average of Last 24 months

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have this calculated member which calculates a moving average for the last 12 months:

```
iif(IsEmpty(Sum({[Time].[Month].CurrentMember:NULL},

[Measures].[Count])), NULL,
Avg
(
   [Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(11) : 
   [Time].[Month].CurrentMember, 
   [Measures].[Count]
))
```

The iif condition is in place because I don't want to get values for future months (with no value), which I do get without it.

What I want to do is have this measure only for the last 24 months since the last not empty month.

I've tried with Tail and Lag but with no luck (I would post my attempts here but after many tries I deleted them and would really not know where to begin again).

Thanks to @whytheq this is the final solution that I used:

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[FirstEmptyMonth]
 AS { Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Time].[Month].MEMBERS
         ,[Measures].[Count]
        )
       ,1
      ).Item(0).NextMember };        
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[MonthsToIgnore]
 AS {[FirstEmptyMonth].Item(0) : NULL}
    + 
      {NULL : [FirstEmptyMonth].Item(0).Lag(25)} ;                
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Moving Average]
 AS IIF
    (
      Intersect({[Time].[Month].CurrentMember},[MonthsToIgnore]).Count = 1
     ,null
     ,Avg
  (
    [Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(11) : [Time].[Month].CurrentMember
   ,[Measures].[Count]
  )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AdvWrks` I've got this:

```
WITH 
  SET [FutureMonthsWithNoData] AS 
    {
        Tail
        (
          NonEmpty
          (
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
           ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
          )
         ,1
        ).Item(0).NextMember
      : NULL
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[blah] AS 
    IIF
    (
        Intersect
        (
          {[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember}
         ,[FutureMonthsWithNoData]
        ).Count
      = 1
     ,null
     ,1
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[blah]
  } ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns this:

[image]

So what I am saying is that you could create this initial set of `FutureDatesWithNoData` and then use that set to create a condition within your script. The set would be (I think) this in your cube:

```
SET [FutureMonthsWithNoData] AS 
{
    Tail
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Time].[Month].[Month].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Count]
      )
     ,1
    ).Item(0).NextMember
  : NULL
}
```

Your measure would then be as follows:

```
IIF
(
    Intersect
    (
      {[Time].[Month].CurrentMember}
     ,[FutureMonthsWithNoData]
    ).Count
  = 1
 ,NULL
 ,Avg
  (
    [Time].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(11) : [Time].[Month].CurrentMember
   ,[Measures].[Count]
  )
)
```

If you want to also exclude months prior to 24 months ago then this script sums up the logic:

```
WITH 
  SET [FistEmptyMonth] AS 
    {
      Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
       ,1
      ).Item(0).NextMember
    } 
  SET [MonthsToIgnore] AS 
      {[FistEmptyMonth].Item(0) : NULL}
    + 
      {NULL : [FistEmptyMonth].Item(0).Lag(24)} 
  MEMBER [Measures].[blah] AS 
    IIF
    (
      Intersect({[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember},[MonthsToIgnore]).Count = 1
     ,null
     ,1
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe I didn't explain my problem well enough. While this indeed hides the future months, my main problem is that I want to get only the last 24 non-empty months. For instance if the last non-empty month is May 2015, I want to include months only as far back as June 2013 until May 2015. So basically, hide both future months and months that are >24 months back from the last non-empty one.

Comment: we can just use FutureMonthsWithNoData to create another set

Comment: After adapting the last script and adding the Avg() part I now have exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: @user4483037 pleasure ...I enjoyed playing with this script. Thank you. Could you maybe edit your question with the final code you used.